# Dodgie doing it meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I'm listening to this giving advice on how to meet women and he says, "...you are having problems starting a conversation with girls, because you know it hasn't worked in the past and frankly you're projecting those onto other people and you think that other people think  the same way about when you do it and that has also got to do with the fact that you haven't done it successfully and maybe have done it in a bad way, in a way that never felt right for you and so underlying it all again is that you probably felt you've learned the wrong process, or you really haven't realized that's the wrong process but just didn't work for you... You felt **dodgie doing** it..." I've probably misspelled it. What does that mean?

Go to 7:20 on the following link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXsl1P87PD4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speaker has a British accent. 'Dodgy' spelled thus is quite common in relaxed or informal British English, meaning doubtful, risky, dangerous, difficult, likely to fail, etc. Also used for something dubious, illegal or wrong. Fraud and theft are dodgy things to get involved in. If one feels dodgy while doing something one feels unsure, nervous, uneasy, scared, apprehensive, etc. There is another usage that may possibly be relevant in the context of physical feeling - one might 'feel dodgy' when in the initial stages of food poisoning or indigestion after eating e.g. a 'dodgy curry' or 'dodgy kebab'

[Dodgy (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dodgy)

Comment: I think pick-up artists and instructors are dodgy.